# does vaadin 12 charts support zooming from java and declarative html?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I found https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zoomType which implies that zooming is possible, but I couldn't figure out either

1. the java code to enable zooming or
2. the html code (in the declarative template html files) to enable zooming.

Is zooming automatically/easily supported in Vaadin 12 charts just like it is with highcharts? (In highcharts, it's a simple option to enable...)

(Similarly, highcharts supports panning, and probably a bunch of other nice "sexy"/"useful" features -- how do we get those in Vaadin?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set pinchType via Java API

```
Configuration conf = chart.getConfiguration();
conf.getChart().setZoomType(Dimension.XY);
```

You can see it action in the [scatter and polygon java demo](https://charts.demo.vaadin.com/ScatterAndPolygon) por instance

I don't think there is declarative API for setting zoomType specifically, but you can use the additionalOptions property of the component to set the zoomType
This [area range demo](https://charts.demo.vaadin.com/vaadin-charts/#/area-range) shows how to set zoomType via additional options